# Google Earth stereoscopic 3D browsing

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, google-earth

One of the things I like very much in Google Earth is Flight Simulator. It would be great if one could use a red-cyan glasses for 3D effect using stereoscopic (anaglyph) rendering.

On Windows there are a few solutions - is there something similar for Ubuntu?

Comment: I've found an old Compiz plugin called *Anaglyph*. This might work well with GE also. [Here](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-compiz-anaglyph-plugin-real-3d-screenwindow-in-ubuntu) is the link to tutorial on how to set it up. However, it doesn't work. It shows up in CompizConfig and you can enable it but there are no other settings which should be there (Hotkey for example, which I found out somewhere it was F12). I haven't been able to make it work. Still researching though - and if anyone has more knowledge to share, fear not and speak up!

Comment: Update: I have found a [new version](http://ddudek.pl/?p=39) of Compiz Plugin mentioned earlier. It works but not for GE. After some thinking that's obvious because we would need a plugin made specifically for GE due to the technical specifics. Searching on.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/stereowrap/ looks interesting...

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: Seth, yes, I am. There is even an open bounty for the answer.

Comment: @PrimožKralj The bounty was started after Seth's comment - in fact, the bounty is a reaction to the temporary closure of this question - it's very well answerable and it needs an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Google is not supporting Linux yet.  Although they've been promising for a long time.  There are alternative available, but not as good.  As much as I hate saying this, but the only way at this point in time is either Windows or Mac.

> Google Earth has received so much press coverage that many users will
>   appreciate that it is one of the coolest applications to download. In
>   brief, it is a feature-laden 3D virtual globe, map and geography
>   browser which lets users zoom in on their world with fantastic detail.
>   View satellite imagery, maps, terrain, 3D buildings and even explore
>   galaxies in the sky. This application allows the exploration of rich
>   geographical content, save toured places and share with others. The
>   software maps the earth by the superimposition of images obtained from
>   satellite imagery, aerial photography and GIS 3D globe.
>
> Google Earth is undoubtedly a very impressive application, and it is
>   extremely hard not to admire the wealth of features that it offers.
>   Its satellite images are unrivaled, it provides useful and accurate
>   statistical information, and the software has many practical benefits,
>   such as helping to find locations and give driving directions. In
>   terms of functionality, this application earns our highest praise. We
>   use the software on a regular basis on both desktop and mobile devices
>   (the latter under Android). However, whilst Google Earth is available
>   to download without charge, Google do not release the software under
>   an open source license. There are a number of applications which are
>   credible open source alternatives to Google Earth. Whilst none of the
>   software applications featured in this article have all of the
>   features offered by Google Earth (although some offer some different
>   features), and they are not exactly comparable, they are all worthy of
>   investigating.
>
> [World Wind](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20110724150627158/WorldWind.html) Virtual globe initially developed by NASA's Learning
>   Technologies project
>
> [Marble](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20110724150657944/Marble.html) Combination atlas/virtual globe
>
> [Virtual Ocean](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20110801152708160/VirtualOcean.html) Integrates the GeoMapApp tool suite with the NASA
>   World Wind 3-D earth browser
>
> [ossimPlanet](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20110801152343417/ossimPlanet.html) Accurate 3D global geo-spatial viewer
>
> [GeoMapApp](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20110801163140174/GeoMapApp.html) Earth science exploration, global topography database,
>   and visualization
>
> [OpenStreetMap](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20110802155240951/OpenStreetMap.html) A copyright free alternative to Google Maps

I hope that Google will support Linux for the plugin too. I think the
best way to show that there is a need for Linux support is to [vote for
the feature request #117 on the feature tracker](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=117).

<sup>Source:[Linux Links](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20110724152349969/VirtualGlobe.html)</sup>